# EC2上でWordPressをインストールし、php56-gdをインストールするとApacheのテストページが表示される

Tags: php, apache, wordpress

EC2上にたてたWordPressでブログが表示されずApacheのテストページが表示されて困っています。何か考えられる原因や対応があれば教えていただきたいです。

#### 再現手順

- t2.microインスタンスをAmazon Linuxで立ち上げる
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/hosting-wordpress.html に従って、ドキュメントルートにWordPressをインストール
- WordPress上でブログを普通に数ヶ月運用
- 画像を扱いたくなったので、 `sudo yum install php56-gd` をした後に、`sudo service httpd restart`を実行
- ブログにアクセスする
- ブログが表示されず、Apacheのテストページが表示されてしまう

#### 困っていること

- ブログが表示されず、Apacheのテストページが表示されてしまう

#### 問題点

- ブログではなくてApacheのテストページが表示されてしまう（以前ブログが表示できていたのと同じURLなのに)
- /wp-admin/install.php にアクセスすると、Error: PHP is not running と書かれた画面が表示される
- `<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` などと書かれた/test.phpにアクセスするとソースコードがそのまま表示される

#### 原因？

- phpが動かない状態になっている？

#### 補足事項

- php56-gdインストール直後は特に問題ないですが、Apache再起動後に問題が起きる
- php56-gdインストール前にAMIをとっていて、そのAMIから新たにインスタンスを立ち上げ同様の手順を行うとやはり同じ問題にぶちあたる、という再現性がある
- EC2はt2.microを使っている
- 3ヶ月前にインストールしたばかりで、特にソフトウェアのバージョンが古いということはなさそう
- Amazon Linux2ではなくてAmazon Linuxです。
- https://104ichi.com/blog/wordpress-index-source/ を参考に、`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`でtrueにしてみましたが、特にエラー文は表示されません。

何か考えられる原因や対応があれば教えていただきたいです。
ぐぐりましたが、phpが動いていなさそう、、、というところまでしかわかりませんでした。

#### 追加情報

phpのバージョン

```
[root@ip-172-31-29-31 ~]# php -v
PHP 5.6.36 (cli) (built: May 10 2018 17:37:08) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
[root@ip-172-31-29-31 ~]#
```

アクセスのたびに表示されるerror_logのログ

```
[Fri Jul 06 20:07:30.108607 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 7789] [client 124.26.172.220:50094] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

ちなみに、
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html にしたがって、Apacheをインストールしてテストページを表示させるという最低限のことをやってテストページが表示されるときと何かエラーログに差分がないかどうか見てみました。この場合は、さきほどの
`DirectoryIndex (index.html) found`
ではなくて、
`DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.php) found`
となりますね。差分が気になります。

この差分を受けて、そして下記のようにindex.phpを追記してみると、index.phpのソースコードがそのまま表示されてしまいます。

```
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

#### コンソール上でのphpの実行

`<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>` と書いたsample.phpをコンソール上で実行すると、問題なくphpinfoの情報が表示されます。（細かく一行一行内容を確認はしてないですが）

Comment: phpのバージョンは何を使っているのでしょうか?(php56-gdをインストールしているので、使用しているphpのバージョンも5.6でしょうか。) また、apacheのエラーログ(/var/log/httpd/error_log)に何かエラーは出力されていないでしょうか?

Comment: ありがとうございます。情報を質問に追記しました。5.6でエラーログにはindex.htmlにマッチするものがないよ、というログですね

Comment: 現時点で最新の[チュートリアル: Amazon Linux AMI を使用して LAMP ウェブサーバーをインストールする](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html)に従って環境を構築されていたのであればPHP7.0が入っている気がするのですが、如何でしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。たしかに最新版だと7.0ですね。回答するならば、私が参照したときは5.6だったんだと思います。このバージョンの違いになにか解決のヒントがあるということですね。もう少し説明いただきたく。。。

Comment: historyをあさってみたら、ドキュメントとかわらず、7.0をインストールしてました！さらにAMIから状態を復旧して、php56-gdインストールの前後でphp -vしてみると、7.0から5.6に変わってました！この辺が原因っぽいので少し調べています

Comment: sudo yum install php70-gd.x86_64 したら無事に解決しました！ありがとうございました！動かなくなったWordPressがのってるインスタンスは削除します。